# XPath to find an element skipping unknown number of levels in between

Tags: c#, xpath, .net-core

I have an XML document which loaded in `XDocument`. Is there a single XPath query I can write to select a node by using partial path?

document:

```
<root> -- level 0
. . .
  <node-12> -- level 1
  . . .
    <month-node month="Jan"> -- level unknown
```

there are several nodes of type node-xx and I want to parse them in separate threads but the target month-node could be at different levels in different nodes.. I am reluctant to walk the whole tree manually to avoid complexity and also I need the parsing to be fast.

Another consideration - it is more likely that tree structure would change where the dots are ... but less likely the names of the nodes in questions will change.

is there something like `/node-12/*/month-node` query?

Comment: Using the `//` path will work, but it can be very slow. | In general, using xpath is quite slow. If you want to process xml quickly, I would recommend linq to xml. Or at least [compiled xpath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.xpathexpression.compile?view=net-5.0) with XPathNavigator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//node-12//month-node
```

You should skip both path to `node-12` node and `month-node` node, so `//` required before each of these elements